# HiveQL - Efficient geoip discovery for big data

Tags: sql, hadoop, mapreduce, hive, hiveql

I am using this hive query  to discover all accounts' country codes. The problem is that the join is exploding the data set to unmanageable sizes, and even the job fails to complete sometimes.

**What is a fast and efficient way to accomplish this geoip lookup query? Use of Hive is not mandatory**

```
SELECT /*+ MAPJOIN(geoip) */
  data.account_id, geoip.country_code
FROM data JOIN geoip
WHERE data.ip_num BETWEEN geoip.begin_ip_num AND geoip.end_ip_num
```

Hive does not support `BETWEEN` inside `ON` clauses. Also, the `WHERE` filter is only applied after the join is complete. Any tips would be useful too. I am currently trying to solve this using a custom MapReduce job. Anyone have some ideas?

#### Info

- `geoip` table is around 1MB in size
- Hadoop cluster only has 12 map slots and 12 reduce slots
- I have tried to bucket the geoip table based on the `begin_ip_num` first octet (ex: the `123` of `123.0.0.0`), and then use the condition in the `JOIN` clause like `FROM data JOIN geoip ON (data.first_octet_bucket=geoip.first_octet_bucket)`. This technique does not work since some rows will be left out.

Comment: Do you looking for solution in Hive or using pure HiveQL ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The chosen solution in the end was to bypass Hive. We serialize the geoip table as a regular java TreeMap, and upload it to custom mappers using Hadoop's DistributedCache.

Comment: Thanks! It is awesome fast compared to the other half solutions I tried before too

Comment: @beefyhalo , could you point us to any resources describing how to do this in more detail?

Comment: A year later, we are using the maxmind java api and the binary GeoIp.dat file supplied from the maxmind website

Answer (score 1):

Try enabling predicate push down.

Open the file:

```
 $HIVE_CONF_DIR/hive-site.xml
```

Add:

```
<property>
  <name>hive.optimize.ppd to true</name>
  <value>false</value>
  <description>Whether to enable predicate pushdown</description>
</property>
```

Reference:
[PredicatePushDown.html](http://hive.apache.org/docs/r0.5.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/ppd/PredicatePushDown.html)

Answer (score 0):

I guess that are no simple solution for now. No non-equi joins support s#c#s. Here is some solution https://reviews.facebook.net/D4137 . BTW good luck.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think there is an easy way to transform to a non-equi join equivalent. At the moment, I'm trying to write a custom MapReduce script to fix this

Answer (score -2):

SELECT
   d.account_id,d.a,d.b,d.c,i.country_code
   FROM data d
   OUTER APPLY
   (SELECT
          TOP 1 
          FROM geoip g
          WHERE d.ip_num BETWEEN g.begin_ip_num AND g.end_ip_num
   ) i

salute